# Sheets API: Append Row with hidden columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-apis-explorer

I have a "appendRow" function for insert rows in the Google sheet called "Data", and this sheet has a column called "Id" (**A** column) which is hidden by client request.

```js
function appendRow() {
  var spreadsheetId = "SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var range = "Data!A2:C";
  var resource = {
    values: [
      ["1", "James", "jam10@gmail.com"]
    ]
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append(resource, spreadsheetId, range, {
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"
  });
}
```

However, when I execute this function, the result is not the expected, as seen in the image.
[image]

I appreciate any information, idea or solution that can help me to resolve this incident. Regards.

Comment: This seems to be likely a bug with Sheet API v4, given that I can append data to a hidden column when using the SpreadsheetApp's appendRow() method (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) & I can replicate the same behavior using your script. So far, I have not seen any open/active issue reports similar to this (the info from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45577637 is the only thing that's quite related to this matter). However, you may also want to report this behavior at https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker.

Comment: Logged on the issuetracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213130197

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  sh.appendRow(["1", "James", "jam10@gmail.com"]);
}

//row must be 2d array
function appendRows(rows) {
  var spreadsheetId = "SPREADSHEET_ID";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SSID");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, sometimes I need to insert multiple rows in the Sheet.